# Can't figure out why I'm getting "undefined index" for one section of code but not another

Tags: php, html, undefined-index

I have several "multiple" select boxes I'm pulling data from. The first two work fine, but when I get to the third, either `isset($_POST('name'))` returns false, or, if I take it out, I get an "undefined index" notice.

I've tried copypasting the code and changing the names, retyping, changing the variable name in both the HTML and the php. Right now I'm banging my head against the keyboard.

The html:

```
<div class = "streamingPlatform">
        <label> <span class = "headings"> Streaming Platform </span>
            <select name = "platform[]" multiple = "multiple" size = "3">
                <option value = "amazon"> Amazon Prime </option>
                <option value = "apple"> Apple TV+ </option>
                <option value = "crunchy"> CrunchyRoll </option>
                <option value = "disney"> Disney+ </option>
                <option value = "hbo"> HBO Now </option>
                <option value = "hulu"> Hulu </option>
                <option value = "netflix"> Netflix </option>
                <option value = "showtime"> Showtime </option>
                <option value = "starz"> Starz </option>
            </select>
        </label>
        </div>
        <div class = "rating">
        <label> <span class = "headings"> Rating </span>
            <select name = "mpaa[]" multiple = "multiple" size = "3">
                <option value = "g"> G </option>
                <option value = "pg"> PG </option>
                <option value = "pg13"> PG-13 </option>
                <option value = "r"> R </option>
                <option value = "nc17"> NC-17 </option>
            </select>
        </label>
        </div>
```

The php:

```
if(isset($_POST['platform']))   
    $platform = $_POST['platform'];
  if(isset($_POST['mpaa']))
      $mpaa = $_POST['mpaa'];
```

Currently $platform will return values, $mpaa will not. If I remove the `if(isset($_POST['mpaa']))` from before `$mpaa = $_POST['mpaa'];` I get the "undefined index" notice on that last line.

HTML to submit to php:

```
<form method="POST"  action="simpleSearch.php">

        <div class = "searchBar">
        <p>Search Movies: 
        <input type="text" name="movie_name" />
        <input type = "submit" value = "Search" />
```

Comment: How are you sending or submitting this data to the php? This code looks all right.

Comment: Try to work with brackets in the if statement.

Comment: @RocketNuts Edited the post. Just using a submit button to post.

Comment: What happens if you insert this line before your 4 lines of php code: `$platform = $mpaa = 'NONE';` to initialize them to dummy strings, and after your 4 lines, add: `echo 'Test: platform = '.json_encode($platform).' / mpaa = '.json_encode($mpaa);` to debug output those two vars. Does it make a difference if you select none, one, or several options in either selection boxes before submitting?

Comment: @RocketNuts The test returns "NONE" for mpaa no matter what selections are made.

Comment: @hamahara OK that's pretty weird. Can you try with this test php file: https://pastebin.com/raw/hPNn88Le This pretty much contains just your code + html header. You can save this as a random separate .php file on your webserver and visit it. By using `method='post'` and no explicit `action` attribute it will just post the results to itself, i.e. re-visit the same file again. When I try it on my local apache + php7, it works fine, I'm getting correct results for both variables.